# Getting error: ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined while using react-speech-recognition in nextjs13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, speech-recognition, regenerator-runtime

**I'm getting the error`ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` in nextJS13**

I am using Redux toolkit.

[Link to my project](https://github.com/leorobertreid/leogpt-web). Note: the code where I get the error is under the nextjsfrontend branch.

I'm a beginner at web dev, and especially nextjs, so please don't be too harsh.

My SpeechRecognitionComponent file which is triggering the error:

```
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, {useSpeechRecognition} from "react-speech-recognition"

function SpeechRecognitionComponent() {
  const {
    transcript,
    interimTranscript,
    finalTranscript,
    resetTranscript,
    listening,
  } = useSpeechRecognition();

  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
    return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>Microphone: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <p>{transcript}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default SpeechRecognitionComponent
```

My layout.js file:

```
import './globals.css'

import { Providers } from "@/redux/provider";

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Leo GPT',
  description: 'An AI that immitates me',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <header>
            <h2>Leo GPT</h2>
          </header>
        {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

My _app.js file:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

**According to [the docs](https://github.com/JamesBrill/react-speech-recognition#regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined), if you get this error, you need to do npm install regenerator-runtime and than import it in _app.js, but I did that:**

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

I still get the error.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, any help would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `metadata`, you are working on `nextjs13 app` directory. so you should import it in `RootLayout` component

```
"use client"
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

Comment: I tried importing 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' in my RootLayout component. However, this does not make it stop the error.

Comment: Can u share gthub repo?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/leorobertreid/leogpt-web is my repo. The error-prone code is in the nextjsfrontend branch.

Comment: that repo is not `next.js`. are u sure u sent the correct link?

Comment: Yeah. You need to go under the nextjsfrontend branch. The frontend on the main branch is vanilla react.

Comment: Also make sure it is client component